# Does ((a^x) ^ 1/x) == a in Zp? (for Jablon's protocol)

Tags: security, math, encryption, biginteger, modulo

I have to implement Jablon's protocol ([paper](http://www.jablon.org/jab01.pdf)) but I've been sitting on a bug for two hours.

I'm not very good with math so I don't know if it's my fault in writing it or it just isn't possible. If it isn't possible, I don't see how Jablon's protocol can be implemented since it relies on the fact that ((gP ^ x) ^ yi) ^ (1/x) == gP^yi .

Take the following code. It doesn't work.

```
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger("101");
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("83");
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger("13");
    BigInteger ax = a.modPow(x, p);
    BigInteger xinv = x.modInverse(p);
    BigInteger axxinv = ax.modPow(xinv, p);

    if (a.equals(axxinv))
        System.out.println("Yay!");
    else
        System.out.println("How is this possible?");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not calculating k<sup>(1/x)</sup> correctly.  We need k<sup>(1/x))<sup>k</sup></sup> to be x. [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Fermat.shtml) tells us that k<sup>p-1</sup> is 1 mod p.  Therefore we want to find y such that x * y is 1 mod p-1, not mod p.

So you want `BigInteger xinv = x.modInverse(p-1);`.

This will not work if x shares a common factor with p-1.  (Your case avoids that.)  For that, you need additional theory.

If p is a prime, then r is a primitive root if none of r, r^2, r^3, ..., r^(p-2) are congruent to 1 mod p.  There is no simple algorithm to produce a primitive root, but they are common so you usually only need to check a few.  (For p=101, the first number I tried, 2, turned out to be a primitive root.  83 is also.)  Testing them would seem to be hard, but it isn't so bad since it turns out that (omitting a bunch of theory here) only divisors of p-1 need to be checked.  For instance for 101 you only need to check the powers 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25 and 50.

Now if r is a primitive root, then *every* number mod p is some power of r.  What power?  That's called the [discrete logarithm problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and is not simple.  (It's difficulty is the basis of RSA, which is a well known cryptography system.)  You can do it with trial division.  So trying 1, 2, 3, ... you eventually find that, for instance, 83 is 2^89 (mod 101).

But once we know that every number from 1 to 100 is 2 to some power, we are armed with a way to calculate roots.  Because raising a number to the power of x just multiplies the exponent by x.  And 2^100 is 1.  So exponentiation is multiplying by x (mod 100).

So suppose that we want y ^ 13 to be 83.  Then y is 2^k for some k such that k * 13 is 89.  If you play around with the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) you can realize that k = 53 works.  Therefore 2^53 (mod 101) = 93 is the 13'th root of 89.

That is harder than what we did before.  But suppose that we wanted to take, say, the 5th root of 44 mod 101.  We can't use the simple procedure because 5 does not have a multiplicative inverse mod 100.  However 44 is 2^15.  Therefore 2^3 = 8 is a 5th root.  But there are 4 others, namely 2^23, 2^43, 2^63 and 2^83.

Comment: It's so unfair that I can only give you +1. This answer clearly deserves at *least* +2.